# SQL INSERT doesn't work but I don't know why

Tags: mariadb, mysql-error-1064

```
INSERT INTO wagers (id, creator_addr, title, platform, 
 region, match, wager_amount, currency, status, isDeleted) 
VALUES ("a033bbae-e472-4f86-a463-844358511aa4", "addr", "title", "platform", 
"region", "match", 100, "USD", 1, 0)
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'match, wager_amount, currency, status, isDeleted) VALUES ("a033bbae-e472-4f86-a4' at line 1

DB Table: https://i.gyazo.com/947505729979cd9c756aaf0e5ffc9b43.png

Answer (score 4):

I think this is because "match" is an SQL statement (like "WHERE" and "FROM").
Try it with the column name between backticks:

```
INSERT INTO wagers (id, creator_addr, title, platform, region, `match`, wager_amount, currency, status, isDeleted) VALUES ("a033bbae-e472-4f86-a463-844358511aa4", "addr", "title", "platform", "region", "match", 100, "USD", 1, 0);
```

Comment: Good answer, but FYI MySQL and MariaDB use back-ticks for delimited identifiers by default. Double-quotes are standard in other brands of SQL.

Comment: @BillKarwin Good addition, I adjusted it, Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

mazch is ine of the [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)
You can use backticks for column names, so tat it will not cause a problem

```
INSERT INTO wagers (id, creator_addr, title, platform, region, `match`, wager_amount, currency, status, isDeleted) 
VALUES ("a033bbae-e472-4f86-a463-844358511aa4", "addr", "title", "platform", "region", "match", 100, "USD", 1, 0)
```